# Mapping several columns from sql to a java object

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am trying to retrieve and process code from JIRA, unfortunately the pieces of information (which are in the Metadata-Plugin) are saved in a column, not a row.
[Picture of JIRA-MySQL-Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqbhi.png)

The goal is to save this in an object with following attributes:

```
public class DesiredObject {
    private String Object_Key;
    private String Aze.kunde.name;
    private Long Aze.kunde.schluessel;
    private String Aze.projekt.name;
    private Long Aze.projekt.schluessel
    //getters and setters here
}
```

My workbench is STS and it's a Spring-Boot-Application.
I can fetch a List of Object-Keys with the JRJC using:

```
JiraController jiraconnect = new JiraController();
List<JiraProject> jiraprojects = new ArrayList<JiraProject>();
jiraprojects = jiraconnect.findJiraProjects();
```

This is perfectly working, also the USER_KEY and USER_VALUE are easily retrievable, but I hope there is a better way than to perform
three SQL-Searches for each project and then somehow build an object from all those lists.

I was starting with

```
for (JiraProject jp : jiraprojects) {
            String SQL = "select * from jira_metadata where ENRICHED_OBJECT_KEY = ?";
            List<DesiredObject> do = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new Object[] { "com.atlassian.jira.project.Project:" + jp.getProjectkey() }, XXX);
        }
```

to get a list with every object, but I'm stuck as i can't figure out a ObjectMapper (XXX) who is able to write this into an object.

Usually I go with

```
object.setter(rs.getString("SQL-Column"));
```

But that isn't working, as all my columns are called the same. (USER_KEY & USER_VALUE)

The Database is automatically created by JIRA, so I can't "fix" it.
The Object_Keys are unique which is why I tried to use those to collect all the data from my SQL-Table.

I hope all you need to enlighten me is in this post, if not feel free to ask for more!

Edit: Don't worry if there are some 'project' and 'projekt', that's because I gave most of my classes german names and descriptions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Hashmap with the Objectkey and an unique token in brackets, e.g.: "(1)JIRA".

```
String SQL = "select * from ao_cc6aeb_jira_metadata";
List<JiraImportObjekt> jioList = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new JiraImportObjektMapper());
    HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Integer unique = 1;
    for (JiraImportObjekt jio : jioList) {

        hmap.put("(" + unique.toString() + ")" + jio.getEnriched_Object_Key(),
                jio.getUser_Key() + "(" + jio.getUser_Value() + ")");
        unique++;
    }
```

I changed this into a TreeMap

```
Map<String, String> tmap = new TreeMap<String, String>(hmap);
```

And then i iterated through that treemap via

```
String aktuProj = new String();
for (String s : tmap.keySet()) {
        if (aktuProj.equals(s.replaceAll("\\([^\\(]*\\)", ""))) {

        } else { //Add Element to list and start new Element }
//a lot of other stuff
}
```

What I did was to put all the data in the right order, iterate through and process everything like I wanted it.

```
Object hinfo = hmap.get(s);
        if (hinfo.toString().replaceAll("\\([^\\(]*\\)", "").equals("aze.kunde.schluessel")) {
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(hinfo.toString());
            while (m.find()) {
                jmo[obj].setAzeKundeSchluessel(Long.parseLong(m.group(1), 10));
                // logger.info("AzeKundeSchluessel: " +
                // jmo[obj].getAzeKundeSchluessel());
            }
        } else ...
```

After the loop I needed to add the last Element.
Now I have a List with the Elements which is easy to use and ready for further steps.

I cut out a lot of code because most of it is customized for my problem.. the roadmap should be enough to solve it though.

Good luck!